# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [489, 1890] KNeighborsClassifier.fit()

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Just trying to do a simple nearest neighbors classification but I'm baffled by this error for:

```
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
neigh.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

which produces:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [489, 1890]
```

Anyone explain it that what i am missing?

Comment: How did you make your train test split?

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the size of your `X_train` and `y_train` samples are not the same. Revisit your train test split and make sure that you are executing it properly. For example if you are using [`sklearn.model_selectin.train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) you would do it like so:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
neigh.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the order of train_test_split argument, it should be in exactly below order

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y)
```

Wrong order produces the error "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples......"